# Automatically add money symbol in input after the number entered

Tags: javascript

I have a input for entering money, also there is a switcher for dollar($) and euro(€) sign. I want to make it, after the user enters a number automatically add dollar and euro sign in order to switcher.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myonoffswitch').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
              $("#1").change(function() {
                  if (this.value.indexOf("$") === -1) {
                      this.value = this.value + ",00 $" ;
                  }
              });
            }
            else{
              $("#1").change(function() {
                  if (this.value.indexOf("€") === -1) {
                      this.value = this.value + ",00 €" ;
                  }
              });
            }
        });
    });
```

but the problem is, after checked the switcher two times, output looks like the example below:
1st check: "2,00$"
2nd check: "2,00 $ ,00 €"

how can i remove the dollar sign when 2nd check.

EDIT: my html is looks like this;

```
  <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" >
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
              <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
              <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
  </div>

<div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Here" name="1" id="1" autocomplete="off" class="inputName" />
</div>
```

Comment: May want to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: I have to make it with inputs

Comment: Can you add your HTML to your question please

Comment: @j08691 I added the html part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.value = this.value.split(',')[0] + ",00 $" ;
```

Will keep everything before the comma, and appendaing what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would think to do.

```
$('#myonoffswitch').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#1").val(addMoneySymbol($("#1").val(), "$"));
  } else {
      $("#1").val(addMoneySymbol($("#1").val(), "€"));
  }
});

$("#1").on('input', function() { 
    $(this).val(addMoneySymbol($(this).val() , $('#myonoffswitch').is(":checked") ? "$": "€"));
});

function addMoneySymbol(value, symbol) {
  var commaLoc = value.indexOf(",00");

  if (commaLoc > -1 && value.length > 0) {
    value = value.split(",00")[0];
  }

  if (value.indexOf(symbol) ===  -1 && value.length > 0) {
    return value + ",00 " + symbol;
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, in line 10, function name should be "addMoneySymbol" but still it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using `toLocaleString()` instead of your own function to format a number/currency properly.

You can format a money-string as following:

```
number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })
```

This will print out: `123.456,79 €`

Read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString